# ESLint not ignoring global variables given in .eslintrc.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, eslint

I am trying to get eslint to ignore a file I'm importing globally using `webpack.ProvidePlugin`, yet the file is still being linted.

```
//file arrangement
- vendor
  `- google.js
- ...
- webpack.config.js

//relevant webpack configurations
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.json'],
  alias: {
    'google': path.resolve(__dirname, './vendor/google.js')
  }
},

....
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'google': 'google'
  })
]

 /*google is successfully available globally*/

//.eslintrc.json
{
  "extends": ["standard", "standard-react"],
  "globals": {
    "google": true
  }
}

//package.json script
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --port 5888",
 ...
"lint": "eslint js/**/*.js webpack.config.js"
```

And yet I am still getting hundreds of linting errors from google.js. It's minified but the webpack docs say that though that's preferred it probably isn't necessary and also the eslint docs don't mention it at all.

I've also tried the comment style of ignoring mentioned in [the docs](http://eslint.org/docs/1.0.0/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments)

```
//google.js
/*global google:true*/
```

#### Why is ESLint still giving me all of these linting errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [global option](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) only refers to using a global variable and has no effect on whether a file is linted or not.

If you don't want to lint a specific file, you can use a `.eslintignore` file to exclude files matching a pattern from the linting process. It is very similar to a `.gitignore`.

You probably want to exclude all vendor files, so you can use the pattern suggested in [Ignoring files from linting](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#ignoring-files-from-linting).

```
**/vendor/*.js
```

This will give you a warning for the files that are being ignored, because you're using a glob, which gets expanded by your shell and therefore you are explicitly passing the file to ESLint (see [Ignored File Warnings](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignored-file-warnings)). You can get rid of that warning by passing a directory instead, and ESLint will lint every JavaScript file in the directory, so your glob is not needed.

```
"lint": "eslint js/ webpack.config.js"
```